# Resize and Reposition DIVS possible using only CSS?

Tags: html, css

Okay, I've got it resizing nicely for devices using a media query. Now I need to reproduce this on a browser resize. Is it possible using only CSS? I'm trying to avoid multiple named divs for scalability (i.e. add another change the min-width etc and it'll still work)

Yes, this may well have been asked before (I really have hunted), but there's just so many ways of framing the question...please indulge me .

The media query with viewport turns the divs into columns of a specific size.

But how on earth do I do this during a browser resize?

If you view this result on device via Chrome inspect etc my point will be abundantly clear.

Thanks all!

```css
#Page {
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  width: 98%;
  /*1000px*/
  background-color: lightgray;
}
#content {
  margin: 0 auto 10%;
  width: 96%;
  background-color: green;
  max-width: 1100px;
}
.col_content {
  float: left;
  margin: auto 1%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: pink;
  min-width: 225px;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {
  #Page {
    background-color: white;
  }
  #content {
    max-width: 400px;
    background-color: green;
  }
  .col_content {
    float: none;
    margin: 1%;
    /*5px*/
    width: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <!--Content-->

  <div class="col_content">
    1
  </div>
  <!--end col_content-->

  <div class="col_content">
    2
  </div>
  <!--end col_content-->

  <div class="col_content">
    3
  </div>
  <!--end col_content-->

</div>
<!--end content-->
```

Comment: If you have your width as `%` instead of `px`, than it will automatically adept to new window width... Your grid system should work on window resize

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {
```

to

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
```

I use the above on my website and it works on browser resizes and on devices.

Comment: Great stuff Jamie. As always the devil's in the detail. I'm a back end developer and quite frankly all the hacks and oddities in web design drive me mad and I end up overlooking the obvious!. So once again thanks much!